# Run clementine minimised and playing

Tags: clementine

I want to launch **Clementine** every time I start my PC, and I want it to be minimised (only tray icon) and playing music.
I added it to **Startup Applications**. What do I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a playlist in Clementine.
Then add the following commands into Startup Applications separately.

```
clementine -y
clementine -p
```

Comment: What command is responsible for what? I only want to start it minimized but without playing music. Can you explain the both commands shortly?

Comment: I think, newer versions already starts minimized without playing music. Have you tried?

Comment: This won't work these days. The `-y` option now does this: "Toggle visibility for the pretty on-screen-display". But, in the Clementine settings, there is an option, "When Clementine starts: Always hide the main window", so maybe you could figure out something.

Comment: Maybe just two entries are required to make it work.